# Get NSData from a file

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata, nsfilemanager

I am trying get NSData of an own file.

My code is as follow, but NSData returned is always nil… (As you can see, I check if the file exists previously)

```
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]){
    NSData * data = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:path];  
}
```

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible that path is a folder, in which case fileExistsAtPath will return YES, but no data can be read.
You can add some extra debugging by reading the data as follows:

```
NSError* error = nil;
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path  options:0 error:&error];
NSLog(@"Data read from %@ with error: %@", path, error);
```

The log output will display the actual error that occurred.

Answer (score 1):

Use This code it works

```
NSString *path = [pathURL filePath];
if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path)
{
NSData *data = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:path];
}
else
{
   NSLog(@"File not exits");
}
```